# How to create product visual swatch attribute programmatically with images in 2.4.6

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4.6, visualswatch

I want to create custom products visual swatch attribute with custom images .

Please let me know if anyone have any example.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add below code in your class in which you need it.**

**Please make sure you have uploaded image to server before you run this code**

```
<?php


namespace Tarun\StackOverflow\Model;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity;
use Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\AttributeFactory;


/**
 * Class CreateSwatchAttributeAndUploadImages
 * @package Tarun\StackOverflow\Model\Plugin
 */
class CreateSwatchAttributeAndUploadImages
{
    /**
     * @var AttributeFactory
     */
    private AttributeFactory $attributeFactory;
    
    /**
     * @var Entity
     */
    private Entity $entity;

    /**
     * @var CollectionFactory
     */
    private CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * CreateSwatchAttributeAndUploadImages constructor.
     * @param AttributeFactory $attributeFactory
     * @param Entity $entity
     * @param CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        AttributeFactory $attributeFactory,
        Entity $entity,
        CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
        $this->entity = $entity;
        $this->groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    public function createSwatch()
    {
        $entityTypeId = $this->entity->setType(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY)->getTypeId();

        $model = $this->attributeFactory->create();
        $data = [
            "frontend_label" =>  [
                0 => "Default Frontend Attribute Label for Swatch",
                1 => "StoreView Frontend Attribute Label for Swatch"
            ],
            "frontend_input" => "select",
            "is_required" => 1,
            "update_product_preview_image" => 1,
            "use_product_image_for_swatch" => 1,
            "visual_swatch_validation" => "",
            "visual_swatch_validation_unique" => "",
            "text_swatch_validation" => "",
            "text_swatch_validation_unique" => "",
            "dropdown_attribute_validation" => "",
            "dropdown_attribute_validation_unique" => "",
            "attribute_code" => "custom_file_swatch",
            "is_global" => 0,
            "default_value_text" => "",
            "default_value_yesno" => 0,
            "default_value_date" => "",
            "default_value_datetime" => "",
            "default_value_textarea" => "",
            "is_unique" => 0,
            "is_used_in_grid" => 1,
            "is_visible_in_grid" => 1,
            "is_filterable_in_grid" => 1,
            "is_searchable" => 1,
            "search_weight" => 1,
            "is_visible_in_advanced_search" => 1,
            "is_comparable" => 1,
            "is_filterable" => 1,
            "is_filterable_in_search" => 1,
            "is_used_for_promo_rules" => 1,
            "is_html_allowed_on_front" => 1,
            "is_visible_on_front" => 1,
            "used_in_product_listing" => 1,
            "used_for_sort_by" => 1,
            "swatch_input_type" => "visual",
            "optionvisual" => [
                "order" =>  [
                    "option_0" => 1,
                    "option_1" => 2
                ],
                "value" => [
                    "option_0" =>  [
                        0 => "Admin Swatch Label for option0",
                        1 => "StoreView Swatch Label for option0"
                    ],
                    "option_1" =>  [
                        0 => "Admin Swatch Label for option1",
                        1 => "StoreView Swatch Label for option1"
                    ]
                ],
                "delete" => [
                    "option_0" => "",
                    "option_1" => ""
                ],
            ],
            "defaultvisual" =>  [
                0 => "option_0"
            ],
            "swatchvisual" =>  [
                "value" =>  [
                    "option_0" => "/s/c/Option1.jpeg", // This image must be there in your project's pub/media/attribute/swatch/s/c/Option1.jpeg
                    "option_1" => "/s/c/Option2.jpeg" // This image must be there in your project's pub/media/attribute/swatch/s/c/Option2.jpeg
                ]
            ],
            "is_pagebuilder_enabled" => 0,
            "source_model" => "",
            "backend_model" => "",
            "backend_type" => "int"
        ];

        $model->addData($data);
        $model->setEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
        $model->setIsUserDefined(1);

        $attributeSetId = 4; //Your Attribute Set Id
        $groupCode = "product-details"; // Your Attribute Set's Group Id

        if ($attributeSetId && $groupCode) {
            // For creating product attribute on product page we need specify attribute set and group
            $groupCollection = $this->groupCollectionFactory->create()
                ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
                ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_code', $groupCode)
                ->setPageSize(1)
                ->load();

            $group = $groupCollection->getFirstItem();
            if (!$group->getId()) {
                $group->setAttributeGroupCode($groupCode);
                $group->setSortOrder(1); // Set your new group sort order here
                $group->setAttributeGroupName("New_Group"); // Set your new group name here
                $group->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);
                $group->save();
            }

            $model->setAttributeSetId($attributeSetId);
            $model->setAttributeGroupId($group->getId());
        }
        try {
            $model->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

**Happy Coding**

Comment: You can load the swatch attribute, if you want to upload files for existing attribute. Please let me know if you need my help for that. @Mukesh Prajapati

Comment: Hello @Mukesh Prajapati, Please let me know if you face any problem or need any assistance. Your confirmation can help others to find their solution having similar issue.

Comment: Thanks you @Tarun , You answer helped me a lot .

Comment: Thank you @MukeshPrajapati, Good to know that it solved your issue. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about image path ? like my images are in mymodule_mymodule/view/frontend or adminhtml/web/images/ folder then how can i assign or import in swatches? please let me know if any idea

Comment: I searched and found that there is constant SWATCH_MEDIA_PATH = 'attribute/swatch' defined in file vendor/magento/module-swatches/Helper/Media.php, which is used to locate file in pub/media directory. You may require to customise that code to use your own file path.

Answer (score 1):

Create one Setup/InstallData.php Like File.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $this->createVisualSwatchAttribute($setup);
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    private function createVisualSwatchAttribute(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $attributeCode = 'your_attribute_code'; // Replace with your desired attribute code
        $attributeLabel = 'Your Attribute Label'; // Replace with your desired attribute label
        $attributeOptions = [
            'option_1' => ['label' => 'Option 1'],
            'option_2' => ['label' => 'Option 2'],
            // Add more options as needed...
        ];

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            $attributeCode,
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => $attributeLabel,
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table',
                'frontend' => '',
                'backend' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 50,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                'group' => 'General',
                'option' => [
                    'values' => $attributeOptions,
                ],
                'frontend_class' => 'visual-swatch', // Important: Set this class to make it a visual swatch
                'user_defined' => true,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'visible_in_advanced_search' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'searchable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'unique' => false,
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Place your attribute images in the following directory: "pub/media/attribute/your_attribute_code/"

pub/media/attribute/color/red.jpg
pub/media/attribute/color/blue.jpg

Comment: Or you can also create it using command.