# Magento 2 Update Attribute Options Data Programatically

Tags: product-attribute, magento2.4.4, attribute-options

I have created the 2 attributes in the Admin 1. Color 2. Material.

I'm going to add the attribute options with swatch image programatically. For this I have created the custom code.

**Import Color:**

```
public function importColorAttribute($csvFinaldata, &$connection)
{
    try {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($csvFinaldata as $rowData) {
            $order["option_{$i}"] = $i;
            $optionsStore["option_{$i}"] = [
                0 => $rowData['option_label'],
                1 => $rowData['option_label_us'],
                2 => $rowData['option_label_ca'],
                3 => $rowData['option_label_au'],
                4 => $rowData['option_label_uk'],
                5 => $rowData['option_label_eu']
            ];
            $visualSwatch["option_{$i}"] = $rowData['swatch_data'];
            $delete["option_{$i}"] = '';
            $i++;
        }

        $data =  [
            'optionvisual' => [
                'order' => $order,
                'value' => $optionsStore,
                'delete' => $delete,
            ],
            'swatchvisual' => [
                'value' => $visualSwatch,
            ],
        ];

        foreach ($data as $key => $attributeOptionsData) {
            if ($key == "swatchvisual") {
                $mediaDirectory = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                $swatchVisualFiles = isset($attributeOptionsData['value'])
                ? $attributeOptionsData['value']
                : [];
                $mediaPath = $this->directoryList->getPath(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
                foreach ($swatchVisualFiles as $index => $swatchVisualFile) {
                    $mainDir = mb_substr($swatchVisualFile, 0, 1, "UTF-8");
                    $subDir = mb_substr($swatchVisualFile, 1, 1, "UTF-8");
                    if ($mainDir !== '#') {
                        $tmpMediaPath = $this->mediaConfig->getBaseTmpMediaPath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $mainDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $subDir;
                        $fullTmpMediaPath = $mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath($tmpMediaPath);
                        $this->filesystemDriver->createDirectory($fullTmpMediaPath);
                        if (!empty($swatchVisualFile)) {
                            if (file_exists($mediaPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'wysiwyg' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'color-swatches' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile)) {
                                $this->filesystemDriver->copy(
                                    $mediaPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'wysiwyg' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'color-swatches' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile,
                                    $fullTmpMediaPath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile
                                );

                                $newFile = $this->swatchMediaHelper->moveImageFromTmp(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $mainDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $subDir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $swatchVisualFile);
                                if (substr($newFile, 0, 1) == '.') {
                                    $newFile = substr($newFile, 1);
                                }
                                $this->swatchMediaHelper->generateSwatchVariations($newFile);
                                $data[$key]['value'][$index] = $newFile;
                            } else {
                                $data[$key]['value'][$index] = "";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'color');
        $attribute->addData($data)->save();
        return $this;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

**Import Material:**

```
public function importMaterialAttribute($csvFinaldata, &$connection)
{
    try {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($csvFinaldata as $rowData) {
            $order["option_{$i}"] = $i;
            $textSwatch["option_{$i}"] = [
                0 => $rowData['swatch_text'],
                1 => $rowData['swatch_text_us'],
                2 => $rowData['swatch_text_ca'],
                3 => $rowData['swatch_text_au'],
                4 => $rowData['swatch_text_uk'],
                5 => $rowData['swatch_text_eu']
            ];
            $optionsStore["option_{$i}"] = [
                0 => $rowData['description_text'],
                1 => $rowData['description_text_us'],
                2 => $rowData['description_text_ca'],
                3 => $rowData['description_text_au'],
                4 => $rowData['description_text_uk'],
                5 => $rowData['description_text_eu'],
            ];
            $delete["option_{$i}"] = '';
            $i++;
        }

        $data =  [
            'optiontext' => [
                'order' => $order,
                'value' => $optionsStore,
                'delete' => $delete,
            ],
            'swatchtext' => [
                'value' => $textSwatch,
            ],
        ];
        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'material');
        $attribute->addData($data)->save();
        return $this;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new LocalizedException(__($e->getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Now I want to update the label and swatch images if already option is exist there.

Also if I pass flag to delete then delete that option.

Please give me some suggestion how can I update and delete the already exist option.

Answer (score 0):

can you please try this [How to create product visual swatch attribute programmatically with images in 2.4.6](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/368694/how-to-create-product-visual-swatch-attribute-programmatically-with-images-in-2/368711#368711)

**If this answer works as your expected, please mark it as accepted. That indicates your issue is solved and makes it easier for others with the same issue to find a verified answer. And that would be great if you click the upvote button for the answer in case you feel it is useful.**

**Happy Coding**